# Can't predict output in SVM in MatLab

Tags: matlab, svm

i have to do my own predict for svm in MatLab for class. I use the next formula:

```
    for i = 1:length(svmStruct1.Alpha)
        salidasvm1 = salidasvm1 + svmStruct1.Alpha(i,:)*svmStruct1.GroupNames(svmStruct1.SupportVectorIndices(i),:)*svmStruct1.KernelFunction(svmStruct1.SupportVectors(i,:),ent,cell2mat(svmStruct1.KernelFunctionArgs(1)));
    end

    salidas1 = max(salidasvm1 + svmStruct1.Bias);
```

The problem is that:

```
svmStruct1.KernelFunction(svmStruct1.SupportVectors(i,:),ent,cell2mat(svmStruct1.KernelFunctionArgs(1)))
```

The prediction always return 0.

Thanks, for helping.

Comment: Did you consider that it's the actual training procedure that isn't producing the right model for you?

Comment: I think it is right because the function predict works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatLab changed the instruction for SVM because last MatLab versions tend to round so early and SVM prediction was always 0.